# Sending bulk email to an array of users using php mailer function

Tags: php, email, syntax, phpmailer

I am using PHP mailer function to send an email to all users on the site(maybe about 100/200). FOr some reason, while i test, the email is sent to the first user the first time. Second time, to the 1st+2nd. And so on. Where is the error in my loop? Please help!

```
    $res    =   mysql_query('select name, email from users');
    while($val  =   mysql_fetch_array($res)){
$emailTo    =   $val['email'];
$name   =   $val['name'];


           $content =   '<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="width:100.0%">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td valign="top" style="padding:15.0pt 0in 15.0pt 0in">
                                <div align="center">
                                <table width="650" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="1" style="width:487.5pt;background:white;border:solid #e0e0e0 1.0pt">
                                <tbody>
                            <tr>
                            <td width="126" style="border: medium none; padding-top: 10px; padding-left: 10px;"><a href="http://test.com/" target="_blank"><img src="images/new_logo.png" alt="test"/></a></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td valign="top" style="border: medium none; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;">
                            <h1 style="margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.25pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:16.5pt">
                            <h1 style="margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:8.25pt;margin-left:0in;line-height:16.5pt">
                            <span style="font-family: tahoma; color: rgb(87, 87, 87); font-size: 15px; font-weight: lighter;">

                            <u></u>
                            <u></u>
                            </span>
                            </h1>
                            <div style="border:solid #e0e0e0 1.0pt; background:#f9f9f9">
                            </div>
                            <h1 style="font-family: tahoma; font-size: 15px; font-weight: 300; color: black; padding-left: 10px;font-weight:bold;text-align:center;">Certificate Of Participation</h1>
                            <p style="margin-right: 0in; margin-bottom: 6pt; margin-left: 35px; line-height: 20pt;">
                            Presented to:<br/>
                            '.$name.'<br/> 
                            for participating in the 2015 Conference.<br/>
                            April 19th, 2015
                            </br>-Team GDFC


                            </p>
                        </tbody>
                        </table>';

            $mail->SetFrom($email, $subject);

            $mail->AddReplyTo($email);

            $address = $emailTo;

            $mail->AddAddress($address);


            $mail->Subject    = $subject;

            $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

            $mail->MsgHTML($content);

            $mail->Send();
  }
    header("location:adminPage.php");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it!
The issue was i'm using a php mailer function code. and the AddAddresses() keeps adding the email ids. So now, i found a ClearAddresses() in the code which i call soon after sending the email! :)

Thank you for all of your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

try to use AddAddress in loop like this,

```
 for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($val); $i++)
     $mail->AddAddress($val[$i]);
```

Comment: for loop within the while loop?? :O

Comment: you have to call $mail->AddAddress() every time to add new recipient address each time, but in your code it add only one address and send the mail, then add the other and so on... so only one  to_address will be added each time

Comment: The val array has 2 elements - name and email. So if ive to add this for loop inside the while loop and replace 
            $address = $emailTo;
            $mail->AddAddress($address);

with  
       for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($val); $i++)
        $mail->AddAddress($val[$i]);

how do i specify $i for email?

Comment: then you have to create an array outside while loop to store email address and put for loop for that array like above answer

Comment: did you got what i mean ?

Comment: you mean like:
 for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($val); $i++){
        //$mail->AddAddress($val[$i]);

    $emailTo = $val[$i['email']]; 
    $mail->SetFrom($email, $subject);
    
    $mail->Address($emailTo,$val[$i['name']]);
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;

    $mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

    $mail->MsgHTML($content);

    $mail->Send();
}

Comment: paste this code before your while loop --->$emailarr = array();
 $emails    =   mysql_query('select email from users');
 while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($emails))
     $emailarr[] = $row;       use this code inside your while loop to add address --->for($i = 0;$i<count($emailarr);$i++)
 $mail->AddAddress($emailarr[$i]['email']);  check whether working or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

Don't store email and name in php variable just directly used the $val['email'] and $val['name'] in the body.

This will solve the issue.

Comment: I wanted to ! But didnt know how to solve the quote issue.
   Presented to:<br/>
  '.$val['name'].'<br/>

??

Comment: replaced like this: Presented to:<br/>'.$val['name'].'<br/>

Comment: I did try that. The names appear fine in each mail. I'm currently trying with 2 emails. So names appear fine in both. But emails are sent twice to the 1st. Once just to the 1st. And once to the 1st and 2nd.

Comment: have you changed this line: $mail->AddAddress($address); to $mail->AddAddress($val['email']);  ??

Comment: Yes! Still same issue!

Comment: Another solution: $emailTo  =   $val['email']; $mail->AddAddress($emailTo);  Use these in your code like previous but add one more thing after $mail->Send(); add $emailTo  = ''; and test.

Comment: Nope! :( still same issue!! :'(

I've even printed the email along with the name in the body. And it appears properly there. But for some reason, addresses are being added! :(